# How to implement a Adobe Photoshop Elements like toolbox in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, toolbar, dockable

Adobe Photoshop Elements is developed in QT. How to implement the dockable and stretchable toolbox at the left of Adobe Photoshop Elements. THX.

[image]

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qdockwidget.html

Comment: You means the toolbox is implemented by QWidget docked at QDockWidget?

Comment: I mean - Photoshop's toolbox is a `QDockWidget` with several `QToolButton`'s added.

Comment: In your opinion, the left `QToolButton` can be added two column `QToolButton`s? And how to do it?

Comment: In `Qt Designer`, using grid layout.